# Joining tables with same column names - ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle.
I am currently working one 2 tables which both have the same column names.  Is there any way in which I can combine the 2 tables together as they are?

Simple example to show what I mean:

TABLE 1:

```
    |  COLUMN 1  |  COLUMN 2  |  COLUMN 3  |
    ----------------------------------------
    |     a      |     1      |      w     |
    |     b      |     2      |      x     |
```

TABLE 2:

```
    |  COLUMN 1  |  COLUMN 2  |  COLUMN 3  |
    ----------------------------------------
    |     c      |     3      |      y     |
    |     d      |     4      |      z     |
```

RESULT THAT I WANT:

```
    |  COLUMN 1  |  COLUMN 2  |  COLUMN 3  |
    ----------------------------------------
    |     a      |     1      |      w     |
    |     b      |     2      |      x     |
    |     c      |     3      |      y     |
    |     d      |     4      |      z     |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Set Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/operators005.htm#i1035612)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`union` set operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6790) to get the result of two queries as a single result set:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from table1
union all
select column1, column2, column3
from table2
```

`union` on its own implicitly removes duplicates; `union all` preserves them. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators005.htm).

The column names don't need to be the same, you just need the same number of columns with the same datatpes, in the same order.

(This is not what is usually meant by a join, so the title of your question is a bit misleading; I'm basing this on the example data and output you showed.)